# using APIs with oauth for single user

Tags: oauth, youtube-api, twitter

I'm trying to make use of various APIs including twitter, youtube, etc because we want to embed recent entries (tweets, videos) on our website.

However, since I'm just retrieving my own data, I'm wondering how I can do this simpler than the multi-step process required by OAuth.

Twitter provides me with my own access token I can use directly, so that kinda works, but I can't find any such token in the YouTube documentation.

So how am I supposed to make use of the api if I just want to get a simple list of stuff? how exaclty am I supposed to authenticate my own website to use my own account?

I think i might have things all wrong and if so please point me in the right direction. I tried using rss feeds but they don't give me as much control over what I retrieve as using the API directly...

any insight or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: okay it turns out I can call the api functions without authenticating myself if all I'm doing is retrieving data. The Hammock library actually supports many different scenarios including oauth, basic, and query-string authorization so I just need to figure out which ones are individually required. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

see my comment above. summary: it depends on the requirements of the individual api

Comment: Please add your comment here into your post. "Above" is a very relative term here on SO :)